# How do you get the filename from a `pdfplumber.pdf.PDF`?

Tags: python, pdfplumber

I have a function that is passed a `pdfplumber.pdf.PDF` argument and I need to reference the filename of the PDF. Is there any way to get the filename from a `pdfplumber.pdf.PDF` class instance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if `pdf` is a `pdfplumber.pdf.PDF`, then you can easily find the filename:

```py
import pdfplumber

pdf = pdfplumber.open('your.pdf')
filename = pdf.stream.name
print(filename)
```